# Evaluate: $\lim_{\theta \to \frac {\pi}{4}}\frac {\cos \theta - \sin \theta}{\theta - \frac {\pi}{4}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> **Evaluate:** $$\lim_{\theta \to \pi/4} \frac {\cos \theta - \sin \theta}{\theta - \pi/4}$$

**My Attempt:**

This limit takes $\dfrac {0}{0}$ form when $\theta =\dfrac {\pi}{4}$.
Here, $\dfrac {0}{0}$ form is an indeterminate form. So how do I make it determinate?

Comment: use l'hopital take the derivative of numeraor and denominator you get $ -sin(\theta)-cos(\theta) $ take the limit now

Comment: @JoseGarcia, Isn't there any other method (except using L'hopital)?

Comment: try L'hopital's Law or Taylor's expansion.

Comment: @pwd, I am not familiar with them.

Comment: Then just google it...

Comment: @pwd That might be a little too much to ask for someone merely wanting to evaluate a limit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without l'Hospital:

$$\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{x-\frac\pi4}=\frac{\cos x-\cos\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)}{x-\frac\pi4}\stackrel{(**)}=\frac{-2\sin\frac\pi4\cdot\sin\frac{2x-\frac\pi2}2}{x-\frac\pi4}=-2\cdot\frac1{\sqrt2}\frac{\sin\left(x-\frac\pi4\right)}{x-\frac\pi4}$$

Finally, you can substitute $\;y:=x-\frac\pi4\;$ , and observe that $\;x\to\frac\pi4\implies y\to 0\;$ , so we get:

$$\lim_{x\to\frac\pi4}\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{x-\frac\pi4}=\lim_{x\to\frac\pi4}-\frac2{\sqrt2}\frac{\sin\left(x-\frac\pi4\right)}{x-\frac\pi4}=\lim_{y\to0}\,-\sqrt2\,\frac{\sin y}y=-\sqrt2$$

$(**)\;\;$ **We used above the trigonometric identity:**

$$\color{red}{\cos\alpha-\cos\beta=-2\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}2\,\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}2}$$

Comment: Nice answer (+1). The identity in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ is one of the [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html).

Comment: @projectilemotion Indeed so, though I never called these trigonometric identites that way. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since your limit is in the form $\frac{0}{0}$, you can use [L'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).
$$\lim_{\theta \to \pi/4} \frac{\cos{\theta}-\sin{\theta}}{\theta-\frac{\pi}{4}}=\lim_{\theta \to \pi/4} \frac{\frac{d}{d\theta}(\cos{\theta}-\sin{\theta})}{\frac{d}{d\theta}(\theta-\frac{\pi}{4})}=\lim_{\theta \to \pi/4}(-\sin{\theta}-\cos{\theta})=\cdots$$
Now that your limit is not indeterminate, you can evaluate your limit by substitution.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that for small $x$ you have $\sin x\approx x$ (from Taylor expansion or l'Hopital), you can write $\theta-\pi/4=x$. Then you can show $$\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)-\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=-\sqrt2 \sin x$$
Then your limit is $-\sqrt2$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\cos(\pi/4) = \sin(\pi/4)$ and hence we can add subtract this in numerator to get the expression as $$\frac{\cos\theta - \cos(\pi/4)}{\theta - (\pi/4)} - \frac{\sin\theta - \sin(\pi/4)}{\theta - (\pi/4)}$$ and one can easily note that these fractions tend to derivatives of $\cos $ and $\sin $ at $\pi/4$ as $\theta\to\pi/4$. Thus the desired limit is $-\sin(\pi/4) - \cos(\pi/4) = -\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=\cos(x)-\sin(x)$, then $f\left(\frac\pi4\right)=0$, and therefore your limit is$$\lim_{x\to\pi/4}\frac{f(x)-f(\pi/4)}{x-\pi/4}=f'\left(\frac\pi4\right)=-\sqrt2.$$